# Problem in solving an inequality.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, proof-writing

> > Let $a,b,c,d \in \Bbb R^{+}$ be such that $a>b$ and $c>d$ with $a+b=c+d.$ If $a > c$ (and consequently $b<d$) then show that
> >
> > $$\sqrt a + \sqrt b < \sqrt c + \sqrt d.$$

**My attempt** $:$

Suppose on the contrary we have

$$\sqrt a + \sqrt b \geq \sqrt c + \sqrt d.$$ Squaring both sides we have $$a+b + 2\sqrt {ab} = c+d + 2 \sqrt {cd}.$$  Since $a+b= c+d$ we have $$\sqrt {ab} \geq \sqrt {cd}.$$ Again squaring we have $$ab \geq cd.$$ Now how do I draw a contradiction from here? I note that If $b \geq c$ then $a+b > 2c$ since it is given that $a>c.$ Now since $c > d$ so we have $a+b > c+d,$ a contradiction to the fact that $a+b=c+d.$ So we must have $b < c.$ $b<d$ as well for the same reason. Hence we can conclude that $a>c>d>b.$ Does it help me anyway in proving the required inequality?

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: Use again $a+b=c+d$. Hint: write $A=a+b=c+d$ and replace $b$ and $d$. Then it's a question about the monotonicity of a quadratic function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: $(a+b)^2-(a-b)^2=4ab$

Can you see how you can use this standard identity together with what you already know?

Comment: Yeah got it @Mark Bennet.

Comment: From the inequality $a> c>d> b$ we can say that $|a-b| > |c-d|.$ So $(a-b)^2 > (c-d)^2.$ Am I right?

Comment: Since $a+b = c+d.$ So we have $(a+b)^2 = (c+d)^2.$ Combining this with the statement in the above comment we can say that $$(a+b)^2 -(a-b)^2 < (c+d)^2 - (c-d)^2.$$ So we have $ab < cd,$ as required.

Comment: Thank you so much @Mark Bennet for your kind help.

Answer (score 5):

$a-c=d-b$ so $(\sqrt a-\sqrt c)(\sqrt a+\sqrt c)=(\sqrt d-\sqrt b)(\sqrt d+\sqrt b)$.

Since $a>b$, $c>d$, we have
$$\sqrt a+\sqrt c>\sqrt b+\sqrt d.$$
Hence $$\sqrt a-\sqrt c<\sqrt d-\sqrt b,$$
as desired.

Comment: Nice proof. It is also equally helpful and easy to digest.